# How to share printer from Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, macos, printer

I've bought MacBook Air and wanted to add a printer. Unfortunately it's not supported for 12.3.1 Monterey hence I decided to share printer that is connected to my old MacBook. This MacBook has 2 boots and I'm using currently Windows 10.
Hence I turned on 'Network discovery' and turned on 'file and printer' sharing on Windows boot.
Now from MacBook Air I could see Windows folder in Finder but printer is not visible.
When I go to MacBook Air 'Printers and Scanner' app ... this printer does not look like "shared".
Looks that something I missed in setting for share Windows printer to MacBook
Could someone help to figure out why my MacBook Air doesn't see Windows printer?
Thanks

Comment: Does the printer have an Ethernet card?  Vastly easier to put the printer on your network.

Comment: I connect to printer via Wi-Fi. This printer is not supported anymore by vendor for this macOS. Hence I decided to print by using shared printer. I was able to share another MacBook and print. After that I also shared this printer from Windows 10 but I can't see Windows printer. I could see only MacBook printer. Hence the question is: why I don't see shared Windows printer!